# Функции С в C++

Tags: c++, css

Возможно, некоторые помнят мой вопрос-просьбу сделать ревизию кода по заданноу тех. заданию.
Собственно, код весьма справедливо раскритиковали, назвали его плохой смесью Си с Си++, что код обладает плохой структурированностью и т.д. и т.п.
Я со всем этим согласен.
Но у меня возникает справедливый вопрос, о том, собственно говоря, как же избегать кода Си в программах на С++, ведь, полностью от кода Си, по-сути, избавиться то невозможно.
Ведь все равно так или иначе нужны будут функции из стандартной библиотеки Си, вроде тех же memcpy или strncpy, указатели на буферы из чаров (хотя все это дело можно и даже нужно инкапсулировать в класс строк), и т.п. и т.д.
В принципе, после чтения Прата, уже сложились кое-какие (весьма скромные) представления о том, как же все-таки должен выглядеть код на C++, но тем не менее.
Например, мне нужно скопировать один кусок памяти в другую область памяти.
Писать для этого отдельный класс, а-ля CopyFactory, который будут хранить указатели на все нужные буферы, определять все необходимые конструкторы и операции, конструктор копирования и оператор присваивания, либо же, для экономии времени, все-таки достаточно будет какого-нибудь smart_ptr с memcpy?
Понимаю что все это относится больше к стилю кода, и каждый пишет програмы по-разному, но тем не менее, есть же наверняка какие-то стандарты либо правила?

Comment: Кусок памяти из `n` элементов типа `T` можно удобным образом завернуть в [`boost::shared_array<T>`][1].

[1]: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_array.htm

Comment: Ну, мы с сестренкой в ее курсовом проекте использовали std::array и std::vector... А потом удивлялись, почему под Борланд Билдером ничего не работает =) Потому что писалось все под g++ (linux), а потом перетягивалось под mingw32, а в колледже вообще пиратский билдер стоял доисторической версии (даже не ембаркадеро)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если сильно нужны именно Сишные функции — используйте. Только не подключайте Сишные заголовочные файлы, используйте [стандартные обертки для них](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/include-c-hdrs-system.html) (вместо math.h, например cmath) для более корректной совместимости с C++; если это нестандартные Сишные функции — оберните сами их [в extern "C"](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/include-c-hdrs-nonsystem.html). Если неясно зачем всё это — попробуйте собрать такой код:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    float a = 1.2;
    cout << abs(a) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Затем тоже самое, но с заменой первых двух строчек на следующее:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>
```

и разберитесь почему поведение программ разное.

Answer (score 5):

> Например, мне нужно скопировать один кусок памяти в другую область памяти

Не работайте с памятью как с "памятью", работайте с ней как с набором элементов. Элементы эти помещайте в контейнер, у контейнера вызывайте операции копирования. Дальше это уже дело контейнера как их копировать - через memcpy как POD типы или через операции копирования в противном случае.

Answer (score 3):

При хорошем стиле можно почти полностью избавиться от любых проявлений C: не работать с памятью напрямую, использовать интеллктуальные указатели. А если вам нужно получить доступ к памяти напрямую, то, ИМХО, лучше написать класс-помощник, чтобы не жалеть потом о времени, потраченном на отладку.

В частности, использование char*, как нечто большее, чем временный буфер для API функций и др., нехорошо, т.к. есть переносимый класс string, являющийся частью Стандарта.

Comment: А что делать с WinApi, функции которого принимают только указатели на строки вроде const LPCSTR? Передавать как str.c_str()?

Comment: @pol500, отбросьте догмы. Пишите, как будет *понятней*.

Comment: @pol500, str.c_str() для этого и нужен, чтобы работать на **НЕ** С++ интерфейсах, в частности WinAPI и C - библиотеки

Answer (score 2):

Хочу примеров. В остальном, как правильно заметили остальные отвечающие, у ТС проблемы с переходом от одной модели программирования к другой. Я лично не понимаю зачем использовать ф-ции strcpy и пр., если можно использовать прекрасный тип `std::string`. Безопасно и надежно. При необходимости `std::string` всегда можно сконвертировать к "старым добрым" Сишным строкам, а потом наоборот из Сишной строки его сконструировать. Единственное, что вызовы старого API будут обрамлены жутковато выглядящим кодом преобразования. Но что поделать?

Касательно работы с памятью - вообще не понял зачем она тут нужна.

Comment: >Безопасно и надежно.

 И тормознуто.

Comment: Пример в посте: http://hashcode.ru/questions/118651/оцените-выполнение-тз#118671

Comment: Насколько помню это было мое сообщение о
сравнении производительности одной задачи
на С и С++.

Непонятно, кто и зачем удалил его ?
Если там были **ФАКТИЧЕСКИЕ** ошибки, то давайте разберемся.

Иначе получается, что какой-то адепт С++ посчитал,
что это **ВРЕДНАЯ** для популярности С++ информация, что *народу такие знания не нужны*.

Comment: Тормознуто - да, но вообще от реализации зависит.  
@avp, вообще-то, да, кто-то удалил. Явно был не я, ибо прав не хватает.

Comment: Забавно, что обычно у всех, кто говорит, что вот, `strncpy` - наше все, а `std::string` тормозит *("давайте свои контейнеры руками напишем - быстрее будет")* в проектах размером чуть больше учебного сразу же начинаются утечки памяти, `sigsegv'ы` и крэши в рандомных местах.

Comment: Соглашусь.

Comment: @Котик, у них это (или другая бяка) на **любом** языке будет, т.к. разруха не в клозетах, а в головах (выражение из произведения Булгакова М.А. "Собачье сердце").

И уж *свои контейнеры руками писать* им очевидно не стоит.